# Moving Glossaries inside an enumerated list

Tags: glossaries

I am trying to include a glossary inside an enumerated list in latex. Normally glossaries seem to be included only as chapters or sections. I need to move it inside an enumerated list. The following is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries} 
\setglossarypreamble{Glossaries to follow here-}
 \makeglossaries

 \newglossaryentry{cbr}{name = {Central Board}, description = {refers
  to the Central Board of the central government}}
 \newglossaryentry{cg}{name = {Central Government}, description =
  {refers to the Government of India}}

\begin{document} 
\section{The present output}
Need to use the words in a system: \gls{cbr} and \gls{cg}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item \printglossaries
 \end{enumerate}

\section{The required output}
Need to use the words in a system: \gls{cbr} and \gls{cg}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item Glossaries follow here--
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Central Board refers to the Central Board of the government;
  \item Central Government refers to the Government of India
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each glossary is started with

```
\glossarysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}
```

By default `\glossarysection` does either `\section*` or `\chapter*`, depending on the document class, so you need to redefine `\glossarysection`. For example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{\item}%
\printglossaries
\end{enumerate}
```

You also need to define a glossary style that uses the `enumerate` environment. The simplest way is probably to define a style that adapts the `list` style:

```
\newglossarystyle{enum}{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}%
   \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item\glsentryitem{##1}%
          \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}
       \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}%
}
\setglossarystyle{enum}
```

The complete example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries} 
\setglossarypreamble{Glossaries to follow here-}
 \makeglossaries

 \newglossaryentry{cbr}{name = {Central Board}, description =
{refers
  to the Central Board of the central government}}
 \newglossaryentry{cg}{name = {Central Government}, description =
  {refers to the Government of India}}

\newglossarystyle{enum}{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}%
   \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item\glsentryitem{##1}%
          \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}
       \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}%
}

\setglossarystyle{enum}

\begin{document} 
\section{The present output}
Need to use the words in a system: \gls{cbr} and \gls{cg}
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{\item}%
\printglossaries
\end{enumerate}

\section{The required output}
Need to use the words in a system: \gls{cbr} and \gls{cg}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item Glossaries follow here--
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Central Board refers to the Central Board of the government;
  \item Central Government refers to the Government of India
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]